# How to copy/mix a function and modify some hardcoded string in it in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So let’s say I have this method:

```
    myMethod1() {
        const a = 1;
        const b = 2;

        return callsAnotherFunction(`foo: ${a + b} $`);
    }
```

Now I would like to have it in another function as well but with `bar` instead of `foo`.

```
    myMethod2() {
        const a = 1;
        const b = 2;

        return callsAnotherFunction(`bar: ${a + b} $`);
    }
```

Is this possible without modifying `myMethod1`?

In a way that if `myMethod1` gets changed to something else, lets say:

```
    myMethod1() {
        const a = 1;
        const CHANGE = 2;

        return callsAnotherFunction(`foo: ${a + CHANGE} $`);
    }
```

I do not have to touch `myMethod2` because it just clones `myMethod1` and changes the `foo` to `bar` thus giving me automatically:

```
    myMethod2() {
        const a = 1;
        const CHANGE = 2;

        return callsAnotherFunction(`bar: ${a + CHANGE} $`);
    }
```

Maybe something like parsing the function into a string, replacing the certain text and outputting a new function? Something like this:

```
    myMethod2() {
        const hypothetical = @toString(myMethod1)
              hypothetical.replace('foo', 'bar');
        return @toFunction(hypothetical);
    }
```

^ the code above is obviously not working because that syntax does not exist, it’s just to clarify what I would like to do.

Is something like this even possible?

Thanks for your help.

*Edit: I can’t edit/access method1*

Comment: Why don't you replace the **result** of the function? Or pass the string as an input? What are you trying to do? XY problem?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. In Javascript everything is possible (just `.toString()` and ---`Function(..)`--- `eval` may work with a pair of `()` around IIRC). But that's definitely not a good idea.

Comment: @user202729 yes, that would actually work: `string = myMethod1.toString()` then `string.replace("foo", "bar")` and then `eval(string + " myMethod1();")`. Why do you consider this a bad idea?

Comment: Try replacing `tio` with `tryitonline`.

Comment: (you can probably see that it replaces `function` with `functryitonlinen` --> syntax error. Manually parse the code is one option, but nevertheless, it's definitely not a good idea)

Comment: yes, I see that it also fails if the method is part of a class and references some inner methods with "this". Apart from that, does it have security issues on top?

Comment: Evaluate arbitrary string (with `eval`) is almost always dangerous.

Comment: As I say in my answer below the real problem is with regart to CSP wich can prevent your code to run if it encounters an `eval` or a `Function("function () {}")` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot modify the function then you cannot modify hardcoded strings in its body. Using the function constructor is not a good idea and will not work in many cases due to [Content Security Policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) which can prevent the use of `eval/Function` (which are considered the same).

Comment: Note that if you can modify myMethod1 then parameterizing it would solve your problem (and it's probably the right way to do it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one function - use a function argument to differentiate between the case. like:

```
myMethod2(type) {
    const a = 1;
    const b = 2;
    return callsAnotherFunction(`${type}: ${a + b} $`);
}
```